# Are inline string arrays in C allocated on the stack?

Tags: c, arrays, string, stack

In C, consider the following "inline" string arrays:

```
char *string1 = "I'm a literal!";
char *string2 = malloc((strlen(string1) + 1) * sizeof(char));
//Do some string copying
...
char string3[] = {'a','b','c','\0'};
char *stringArray[] = {string1, string2, string3};
```

Would `stringArray` simply contain a copy of each of three pointers?

Would the array be allocated on the stack?

Comment: Note: `string3` isn't null terminated. Don't try to use `str(n)len` on it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `stringArray` is allocated on the stack, each of its element is a pointer to a `char`. To be more specific :

- `string1` pointer is on the stack, its value is the address of the first character of a read-only string in the data segment
- `string2` pointer is on the stack, its value is the address of a memory block allocated on the heap
- `string3` is an array which occupies `4 * sizeof(char)` bytes on the stack
- `stringArray` is an array which occupies `3 * sizeof(char *)` bytes on the stack.

Comment: None of the elements are pointers to a `char` array, but rather of type `char *` - that is, pointers to a `char`.

Comment: Actually, string3 would have 4 * sizeof(char) (i.e. one more byte for the null).

Comment: @Lee-Man the question has been edited : I'm correcting my answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes (it does contain copies of pointers (see later)), and yes (the array is on stack).

(`string3` is not a pointer, but rather an array).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code fragment is part of a function (and it looks like it is, since you "do some string copying"), then yes, all but the storage for string2 (since it is malloc()ed) would be on the stack.

Comment: False. `"I'm a literal"` is not allocated on the stack either. It's generally in `.data`.